# Scala/Lift - map function

Tags: scala, lift

I'm using Lift to generate my web front.
In the scala file I have a list: `val testList = List("part1","part2","part3")`
I'm apply a function to each element for the list. For now I just want to make them bold. I know there is another way to make them bold by changing the html code, but that's not the point of this exercise. I'm trying to see if I can generate the html in the scala file as opposed to the .html file.

I defined a function

```
 def formatText(s:String)={
    <B> s </B>
  }
```

and I call `var testList2= testList.map(formatText(_))`

The problem is that in the output all I see is `s s s` in `bold`.  If I put quotes around the `<B>` then the string is escapsed so instead of getting part1 (in bold), I get < B >part1< / B >.

How do I display those strings in bold? Is there a `$s` to tell Lift/scala I mean the variable `s` and no char s in `formatText`?

Comment: FYI you can simply call `testList.map(formatText)` instead of `testList.map(formatText(_))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML-literal "escape" characters (for adding variables, expressions, etc) are `{` and `}`:

```
def formatText(s:String)= <B> {s} </B>
```

Take a look at [Programming in Scala 26.3: XML Literals](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-xml.html#26.3) for more details.

Comment: so everything I put in between `{` `}` is executed as code not as strings. Excellent link!